# Line break in a CardHeader element subtitle (MaterialUI / ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using pretty old Material UI (Ver. 0.20.1) components.

Here's a chunk of my code:

```
return(
  <>
    <Card>
      <CardHeader 
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
      title = {user.name} 
      subtitle={`${user.email}, ${user.phone}, ${user.isproved ? "Yes" : "No"}, Friends: ${user.friends? user.friends : "None"}`} 
      />
    </Card>)
```

So i have a subtitle string with a bunch of variables in it that i wanted to use a line break to separate visually but adding `\n` or even `'...string' + <br/> + 'string...'` doesn't work. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test in a sandBox but if we look in the version 0.20.1 documentation of Material-ui we can read that:

> property: **subtitle**    type: **node**      *Can be used to render a subtitle in Card Header*.

so you can create a node for example a list:

```
const subtitle =<ul><li>{user.email},</li><li>{user.phone},</li><li> {user.isproved ? "Yes" : "No"},</li><li> Friends: {user.friends? user.friends : "None"}</li></ul>;
```

and pass it to `subtitle` like this:

```
return(
  <>
    <Card>
      <CardHeader 
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
      title = {user.name} 
      subtitle={subtitle} 
      />
    </Card>
</>
)
```

**UPDATE:**
I found a codeSanbox template so here a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-material-ui-0200-forked-e52dp)